# if $V\subseteq U\subseteq V\cup W$ then is it true that $U\subseteq W$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

So I am trying to understand if $U$, $V$ and $W$ are three sets such that
$$
\tag{0}\label{0}V\subseteq U\subseteq V\cup W
$$
then the inclusion
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}U\subseteq W
$$
must hold: indeed, what show to follow seems confute \eqref{1}.

So let be $Y$ a not empty subset of a topological space $X$ and thus let be $H$ a subset of $X$ such that
$$
\tag{2}\label{2}\operatorname{bd} Y⊆H⊆\operatorname{cl}Y
$$
So if the last inclusion holds then we observe that the inclusion
$$
\tag{3}\label{3}X\setminus\operatorname{cl}Y\subseteq X\setminus H\subseteq X\setminus\operatorname{bd}Y
$$
holds but we know that
$$
\operatorname{ext}Y=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}Y\quad\text{and}\quad X\setminus\operatorname{bd}Y=\operatorname{ext}Y\cup\operatorname{int}Y
$$
so that by \eqref{3} we infer that
$$
\tag{4}\label{4}\operatorname{ext}Y\subseteq X\setminus H\subseteq\operatorname{ext}Y\cup\operatorname{int}Y
$$
So if \eqref{1} was true then \eqref{4} would implies that
$$
\tag{5}\label{5}\operatorname{ext}Y\subseteq X\setminus H\subseteq\operatorname{int}Y
$$
which is true only if $\operatorname{ext}{Y}$ is empty.

So I ask to clarify if \eqref{1} holds and in particular if it does not hold then I ask to give a more handy counterexample; moreover I ask if \eqref{4} holds when \eqref{2} does. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: Re (4): Note that $X\backslash H\subseteq X\backslash \text{bd}\,Y$ and $\text{ext} \, Y=X\backslash (Y\cup\text{bd}\,Y)\subseteq X\backslash H$, since $H\subseteq Y\cup\text{bd}\,Y$.

Comment: Your title seems to ask about $U\subseteq W$, but you switched in (1) to a claim that $V\subseteq W$.  It seems to be a problem (in either case) purely about set inclusion.  Yet your tags and terminology draw *topology* into discussion.  Once the Question has been nicely Answered (as here), your options to improve the problem statement are limited.

Comment: @hardmath So I was searching for a counterexample showing that $U$ is not contained in $W$ and mathlander give this counterexample: clearly the inclusion $$\{a\}\subseteq\{a\}\subseteq\{a\}\cup\{b\}$$  holds but $$U=\{a\}\not\subset\{b\}=W$$ whether $a$ and $b$ are different. So I will immediately edit the question: thanks for the check!!! ;-)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the check!!! ;-)

Comment: Okay, I think that's better.  The correct conclusion from (0) is that $U\setminus V \subseteq W$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is true if and only if $V \subseteq W$. If this is true, then the second subset relationship implies the result. If this is not true, then $U$ must contain all elements of $V,$ including those outside $W,$ so the statement is false.

Comment: Okay, perfect. Instead what can you say about $(4)$? it is ture, right?

Comment: I don't know any general topology, so I used my set theory knowledge here.

Comment: Okay, anyway I am quite sure it is true so that I upvoted and approved your answer. However if someone want confirm $(4)$ into the comments I will grateful to him! So thanks for the simple counterexample! ;-)

Comment: Your proof that $(2)$ implies $(4)$ is correct

Comment: @Taladris Perfect, thanks for the check!!! ;-)